# How to transform a txt of format [word|NN -0.3 word2 word3] into df with all word in a seperate row plus value

Tags: r, string, dataframe, text

I need help with a .txt that is very unfavourable formated.

The txt is formatted like this with more than 3000 rows.

```
Überfüllung|NN  -0.0048 Überfüllungen
Übergewicht|NN  -0.2011 Übergewichtes,Übergewichten,Übergewichte,Übergewichts
Überhöhung|NN   -0.0048 Überhöhungen
Überlastung|NN  -0.0048 Überlastungen
```

What I like to have is something like this (data frame):

```r
word | value
Überfüllung -0.0048 
Überfüllungen -0.0048   
Übergewicht -0.2011 
Übergewichtes -0.2011
Übergewichten -0.2011
Übergewichte -0.2011
Übergewichts -0.2011
Überhöhung  -0.0048 
Überhöhungen -0.0048
Überlastung -0.0048 
Überlastungen -0.0048
```

...where each word of a row gets an own column combined with the value of the original row.

What I can do is:

```r
word | value
Überfüllung -0.0048 
Übergewicht -0.2011 
Überhöhung  -0.0048 
Überlastung -0.0048
```

with the following code from this page https://www.inwt-statistics.de/blog-artikel-lesen/text-mining-part-3-sentiment-analyse.html:

```r
sent <- c(
  # read txt
  readLines(paste0(getwd(), "/words.txt"),
            encoding = "UTF-8")
) %>% lapply(function(x) {
  # Extracting columns
  res <- strsplit(x, "\t", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  return(data.frame(words = res[1], value = res[2],
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}) %>%
  bind_rows %>% 
  mutate(words = gsub("\\|.*", "", words) %>% tolower,
         value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  # if there are duplicated words
  group_by(words) %>% summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% ungroup
```

However they just use the first word in the left column and neglect all other what is not applicable in my case :/

Do you have any idea how to cope with that issue?

Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
stringr::str_split(rows,"\\||\\s+",simplify = TRUE)  %>%# separate by | or white space of any length
    as.data.frame() %>% # convert to dataframe so we can use dplyr
    mutate(V1 = stringr::str_c(V1,V4,sep = ","))  %>% # join all words in the same row
    select(-V2,-V4) %>% # drop all NNs and column 4
    tidyr::separate_rows(V1,sep = ",") %>% # use separate_rows to separate rows by comma for column 1
    rename(word = V1,value = V3) # rename columns
```

```
            word   value
1    Überfüllung -0.0048
2  Überfüllungen -0.0048
3    Übergewicht -0.2011
4  Übergewichtes -0.2011
5  Übergewichten -0.2011
6   Übergewichte -0.2011
7   Übergewichts -0.2011
8     Überhöhung -0.0048
9   Überhöhungen -0.0048
10   Überlastung -0.0048
11 Überlastungen -0.0048
```

### data I use

```
doc <- "Überfüllung|NN  -0.0048 Überfüllungen
Übergewicht|NN  -0.2011 Übergewichtes,Übergewichten,Übergewichte,Übergewichts
Überhöhung|NN   -0.0048 Überhöhungen
Überlastung|NN  -0.0048 Überlastungen"

rows <- readLines(textConnection(doc))
```

Comment: Wow you are amazing! Just started with my dirty Excel approach what would take me some time and than this answer within few minutes :D As soon as I have enough reputation I vote you up! Thanks a lot!